# I'm creating a plugin that adds toggles to the Wordpress plugin admin page. My toggles display the correct state but do not toggle the state?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, wordpress

I'm working on a Wordpress plugin that adds toggles to the plugin admin. This is really convenient because activating and deactivating plugins is a bummer because it refreshes the page and resets the view to the top of the page. This leads to a lot of needless scrolling and clicking.

SO I made a toggle:

[Toggle example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BLhL3.png)

However I am unable to diagnose why the code displays the toggle correctly but does not actually toggle. I tried getting some AI to weigh in this but to no avail.

The attempt I've recently tried is using the actual URL for the AJAX endpoint...still not working.

Here's the repo: https://github.com/openartist/wp-plugin-toggle/

The PHP:

```
function plugin_activation_toggle_column($actions, $plugin_file, $plugin_data, $context) {
  if ($context === 'all') {
    $status = is_plugin_active($plugin_file) ? 'active' : 'inactive';
    $toggle_class = $status === 'active' ? 'active' : '';
    $nonce = wp_create_nonce("toggle-plugin_$plugin_file");

    $toggle_html = sprintf(
      '<div class="plugin-activation-toggle %s" data-plugin="%s" data-nonce="%s">
        <span class="toggle-switch"></span>
      </div>',
      esc_attr($toggle_class),
      esc_attr($plugin_file),
      esc_attr($nonce)
    );

    // Add the toggle switch at the beginning of the action links
    $actions = array('toggle' => $toggle_html) + $actions;

    // Remove the "Deactivate/Activate" links
    unset($actions['deactivate']);
    unset($actions['activate']);
  }
  return $actions;
}
add_filter('plugin_action_links', 'plugin_activation_toggle_column', 10, 4);

function plugin_activation_toggle_scripts() {
  wp_enqueue_style('plugin-activation-toggle-styles', plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) . 'plugin-activation-toggle.css', array(), '1.1');
  wp_enqueue_script('plugin-activation_toggle-script', plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) . 'plugin-activation-toggle.js', array('jquery'), '1.1', true);

  // Define the AJAX URL for the JS script
  $ajax_url = admin_url('admin-ajax.php');
  wp_localize_script('plugin_activation_toggle-script', 'plugin_activation_toggle', array(
    'ajax_url' => $ajax_url,
  ));
}
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'plugin_activation_toggle_scripts');

function plugin_activation_toggle_ajax_handler() {
  check_ajax_referer('toggle-plugin', 'nonce');
  if (!current_user_can('activate_plugins')) {
    wp_send_json_error('Permission denied');
  }

  $plugin_file = isset($_POST['plugin']) ? $_POST['POST']['plugin'] : '';
  $activate = isset($_POST['activate']) && $_POST['activate'] === 'true';

  if (empty($plugin_file)) {
    wp_send_json_error('Plugin file not specified');
  }

  $plugin_dir = WP_PLUGIN_DIR;
  $relative_plugin_file = str_replace($plugin_dir . '/', '', $plugin_file);

  try {
    if ($activate) {
      activate_plugin($relative_plugin_file);
      // Commented out success message
      // $message = 'Plugin activated';
    } else {
      deactivate_plugins($relative_plugin_file);
      // Commented out success message
      // $message = 'Plugin deactivated';
    }
    wp_send_json_success(array()); // Empty response for success
  } catch (Exception $e) {
    wp_send_json_error($e->getMessage());
  }
}
add_action('wp_ajax_plugin_activation_toggle', 'plugin_activation_toggle_ajax_handler');
```

The JS:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('.plugin-activation-toggle').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var toggle = $(this);
    var plugin = toggle.data('plugin');
    var nonce = toggle.data('nonce');
    var isActive = toggle.hasClass('active');

    toggle.addClass('loading'); // Add a loading class for visual feedback

    $.ajax({
      // **Use the provided AJAX URL variable here:**
      url: plugin_activation_toggle.ajax_url,
      type: 'POST',
      data: {
        action: 'plugin_activation_toggle',
        plugin: plugin,
        nonce: nonce,
        activate: !isActive
      },
      success: function(response) {
        toggle.removeClass('loading'); // Remove loading class
        if (response.success) {
          toggle.toggleClass('active');
        }
      },
      error: function(xhr) {
        console.error('Error: ' + xhr.statusText);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: First question: Did you define `plugin_activation_toggle.ajax_url` ?

Comment: This is wrong: `$_POST['POST']['plugin']`.

Comment: The ajax call seems fine at first sight. Did you try debugging the request itself in the browser? It’s easier if you make it a GET request so you can simply type the ajax url in the browser, append `action`, `plugin` and `activate` as query parameters. And then see what happens.

Comment: @KenLee I believe so here: 

wp_localize_script('plugin_activation_toggle-script', 'plugin_activation_toggle', array(
  'ajax_url' => $ajax_url,
));

Comment: @Klassiak, adjusting that seemed to introduce a fatal error I wasn't able to resolve. I'll try debugging more later.